# How can I automatically display the section link on my one-page Elementor website?

Tags: links, automation, sharing

My website is using long one-page posts for each issue of our magazine and these are navigated through anchor links. I add the anchor links through Elementor. I want to be able to display the section link automatically so people can share that part of the page easily.

For example, [here](https://theyellipages.in/), the section link for the article on naps is `https://theyellipages.in/#silent` . How can I display this automatically so I don't have to manually do it for each section since there are many in a page?

Comment: Display it automatically where? As link that the user can copy the full link from, or in the browser navigation bar, or somewhere else?

Comment: Sorry, I should have been clearer. As you said, I wanted to display it at the bottom of that section so they can copy it easily.

Answer (score 0):

I saw your example link. this use scrollspy to detect user is on what a part in single page. You only need to add the URL hash for the part user view on and your problem will be resolve.

I send you the same simple libraries in Bootstrap. https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/components/scrollspy/

Hope can help you.

Comment: Hi! How do I add the URL hash you mentioned?